# Activities vs Fragments for static menu bar

Tags: android, android-activity, menu, android-fragments, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've developed like 5 Android applications using only Activities (and from time to time Fragments for ViewPagers for instance).

I have to develop a new application targeting Android ICS for tablets and handsets, with a very simple and static menu bar on the top (like 4 buttons on a single line). I don't need any single-pane / multi-pane layout depending on if the user has a handset or a tablet.

Each button of the menu bar will open a different screen, always keeping the menu bar on the top of the application. My question is if using Fragments for each screen instead of Activities is the proper way to achieve this.

Apart from avoiding some code duplication (basically the behavior of the menu bar), I don't see any advantage of using Fragments.

**EDIT**

First of all thanks a lot for answering my question so precisely and so fast.

Your answers have been very helpful for me : for instance I was afraid of having just one single Activity one my app, but I now understand it's rather a good thing.

You wanted to know what my application will actually do, so... there will be like 4 different screens : a News screen, a Videos screen (with live streaming video players), a Search for past videos screen and a basic Contact screen.

Comment: I think yes, using fragments instead Activities is better in this case. Another solution is to make your menu bar a Fragment and then add it to your Activities either dynamically or in XML layout. Also you can try making your menu sliding out which is a new trend in UI design patterns (see YouTube application as an example of this pattern)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I understand the solution with the menu bar as a Fragment. But still, I don't get why using Fragments instead of Activities would be better in this case.

Comment: I think this is the question of personal customs. Usage of Fragments will allow you to handle only one instance of menu rather than creating a new one for each screen. Also I don't know whether it's good or not but Fragments will allow you to build your application on one Activity (maybe this will be good in terms of speed in case you develop something simple). I use Fragments because I have to develop applications with complicated UI (dual panes, sliding menus) so I can't avoid using them, maybe that's why I'd recommend using a Fragment=)

Comment: Your app(as you described it) can be implemented with fragments, just be careful how you handle those resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is if using Fragments for each screen instead of
>   Activities is the proper way to achieve this.

Your scenario is pretty simple and you could go either way. I would choose fragments over activities mainly because:

1. *always keeping the menu bar on the top of the application.* - With a fragment based app you could have a smoother transition between the various screen(and it will also allow you to keep in place the buttons bar).
2. easier communication between the various screens of the app as you'll have all the fragments in one parent `Activity`(but as I don't know what your app does I'm not sure this is something relevant).
3. Your app may be small now but you may get new ideas/requests to improve it in the future and this may be an easier task to do when your app is composed from fragments(which should be designed as loosely coupled components). Again, not knowing what your app does, this may or not may be relevant. An example scenario would be the need(in the future) to insert a `ViewPager` for the content of the app(so you allow the user to also swipe to a page not only click a `Button`). Using fragments this would be very simple as you need to setup the `ViewPager` and insert the content fragments, using `Activities` would mean a lot more refactoring.